# How to use a For loop to create Google Forms checkbox choices

Tags: google-apps-script

I have tried numerous iterations of the code below, with limited success. The logger seems to show the commands correctly, but the form doesn't seem to EXECUTE the commands. After executing, the form just generates a single non defined checkbox.

Given that I have to repeat this checkbox question multiple times with slightly different question phrasing, I'm trying to reduce my code footprint, and hopefully become more efficient.

Here is the snippet of code I have that's failing:

```
    var storerangestart = 9901;
    var storerangeend = 9999;
    page402_cbitem1.setTitle('What stores do you have allocated for this project?');
    var page402array = 'page402_cbitem1.setChoices([\n';
    for (var i = storerangestart; i < storerangeend; i++) {
      var storerangecurrent = i + "";
      page402array += 'page402_cbitem1.createChoice(' + storerangecurrent + '),\n';
    }
    page402array += 'page402_cbitem1.createChoice(' + storerangeend + ')\n]);';
    Logger.log(page402array);
    page402array();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Logger isn't showing you commands, it's showing you a string. Your code has created a string that contains text that *looks like* code, but there is no way to execute the content of that string directly in Google Apps Script.

You've got a good idea - you're just stuck trying to manhandle the wrong object types.

Look at the definition of [`CheckboxItem.setChoices()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-item#setChoices%28Choice%29), you'll see it takes an array of choices as a parameter. The example code may have thrown you because it created the item elements inside the `.setChoices()` method call:

```
item.setChoices([
    item.createChoice('Cats'),
    item.createChoice('Dogs')
]);
```

You could realize the same result this way:

```
var choices = [];                           // create a new array of choices
choices.push( item.createChoice('Cats') );  // Add 'Cats'
choices.push( item.createChoice('Dogs') );  // Add 'Dogs'
item.setChoices( choices );                 // set the array of choices
```

That sets up the opportunity for the loop that you're thinking about. Instead of building a string that contains code, you need to call the various object methods to first build up an array of choices, and then to assign that array as the choices for your form item:

```
var storerangestart = 9901;
var storerangeend = 9999;
page402_cbitem1.setTitle('What stores do you have allocated for this project?');
var page402array = [];
for (var i = storerangestart; i < storerangeend; i++) {
  var storerangecurrent = i + "";
  page402array.push( page402_cbitem1.createChoice( storerangecurrent ) );
}
Logger.log( page402array );
page402_cbitem1.setChoices( page402array );
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much. This was driving me nuts! I'm not a programmer by trade, but can muddle through a lot of 'programming like' tasks such as this...this one just had me stuck because in my first efforts at creating a checkbox array using the .setChoices method vs .setChoice, it kept erroring out, so I thought perhaps the documentation was out of date and that was a deprecated method.

Comment: Glad to help! The code gets easy when you have enough familiarity with all of it, but it's easy to confuse ideas from PHP, javascript on web pages, server-side programming, and of course the Apps Script APIs. I figured that working through the thought process might help with similar future problems.

Comment: @Mogsdad, I've just spent hours trying figure out how to build an array of choices. `var choices = [];                           // create a new array of choices
choices.push( item.createChoice('Cats') );  // Add 'Cats'
choices.push( item.createChoice('Dogs') );  // Add 'Dogs'
item.setChoices( choices );                 // set the array of choices` saved the day. Thank you and an upvote.